# Setter in Interface & Objects into an Array

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

I have slight problems in understanding two little tasks. I try to be specific as I can but I have to translate everything from German, so keep this please in mind. The task is to program a sort of "training-game" where you can build training-sessions and so on. 
My first task is to implement an interface which is filled with three different methods:

- void setCaloryGoal (int caloryGoal) -> sets the caloryGoal
- int getCaloryGoal -> returns the caloryGoal
- double getAchievementDegree -> returns the achievementdegree (burnedcalories / caloryGoal)

Than we have to implement a new class `TrainingsessionWithGoal` where you use the constructor of the superclass `Trainingsession` but you have to add the caloryGoal and I have no idea, how I can implement it from the interface (I am sure, that we have to implement it with the set-method. My current code is this:

```
public TrainingsessionWithGoal(int trainingtime, Fitnessdevice fitnessdevice, int day, int month, int year, int hh, int mm, int caloryGoal) {
    super(trainingtime, fitnessdevice, day, month, year, hh, mm);
    this.caloryGoal = caloryGoal;
}
```

This totally works, but I am pretty sure, that the way I implemented the caloryGoal is not the correct way, because I never use the set-method from the interface. Does anyone have an idea for that?

In the other task, we have to create a new class `TrainingProgramm` in which we implement an arraylist which is filled with different objects of the class `Trainingsession` and the new class `TrainingsessionWithGoal`) and there I have absolutely no idea how to process. I googled everything but couldnt find something that helps me.

This is what I have so far:

```
private ArrayList <Objects> list = new ArrayList <Objects> ();

public TrainingProgramm (String programmName, ArrayList<Objects> list) {
    this.programmName = programmName;
    this.list = list;
}
```

but that obviously doesnt work. It would be very helpful if someone can guide me to the right way.

Comment: Does `Trainingsession` already implement that interface? If not, then `TrainingsessionWithGoal` must be declared as implementing that interface, which will force you to implement those three methods. That could be the place to start.

Comment: I guess that `this.kalorienZiel = kalorienZiel;` should actually be `this.caloryGoal = caloryGoal;`

Comment: Yes, I already implemented the interface in TrainingsessionWithGoal with this:
@Override
    public void setKalorienZiel(int kalorienZiel) {
        this.kalorienZiel = kalorienZiel;
    }

but I dont think, that this is the solution either.

Comment: @Lino yes thats true, I forgot to translate this little line :D

Comment: *but I am pretty sure, that the way I implemented the caloryGoal is not the correct way*. This is pretty opinion-based, but I think you did it the right way. As long as `caloryGoal` is not `final` in `TrainingsessionWithGoal` the user of your class can still use the setter to change the value of `caloryGoal`

Comment: @Lino Yes you are right. Tried it with the set-method and changed the value and it works! Thank you, never thaught of that before! Now I only need help with this ArrayList :/

Comment: For your second task, just change `ArrayList<Object>` to `ArrayList<? extends Trainingsession>` that way you accept *any* list which contains instances of the class (and subclasses of) `Trainingsession`. And thus you can iterate over that list with e.g. a `for-each-loop`: `for(Trainingsession session: list){/*your code*/}`

Comment: @Lino better than than making the List of type TrainingSession would be to use the whatever named interface. And type of the field and the parameter of the method should be a List, not an ArrayList. And those should be named properly - instead of list give them more semantic names.

Comment: @juwil you're complelty right. You might want to post an answer with your suggestions, and mine aswell if you want to

Comment: @Lino I did as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You could, as suggested by Lino, change the `ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList<? extends Trainingsession>`. Even better you use your (however named) Interface for this. 
And type of the field and the parameter of the method should be a List, not an ArrayList. And those should be named properly - instead of list give them more semantic names. That way you would have sth. like this:

```
private List<YourInterface> sessions = new ArrayList <YourInterface> ();
public TrainingProgramm (String programmName, List<TrainingSessionInterface> sessions) { ... }
```